# Shift by type width does not return zero

Tags: c, bit-shift

For a simple obfuscation assignment, I would need to shift an `unsigned int` until it becomes zero.

```
unsigned int a = 12;
a <<= sizeof(a) * 8;
printf("%u", a);
```

I compile it using `gcc test.c -o bin`, GCC warnings:

```
warning: left shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
```

When I execute it, it returns `12`. But it should be `0` undoubtedly. Has GCC ignored compiling that line of code? or I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is undefined behavior.

> In any case, if the value of the right operand [of << or >>] is negative or is greater or equal to the number of bits in the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

(quote from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

Also, the article says that:

- Unsigned overflow and underflow are well-defined, extra bits are truncated.
- Signed overflow with `<<` is undefined. (Since C++14 it's well-defined if a resulting value is represenatble with an unsigned version of the left type. Then the tesult is converted back to signed.)
- `>>` applied to signed negatives is implementation-defined. (Cppreference says that on most architectures it copies the leftmost bit.)
- `<<` appled to signed negatives is undefined.

---

Those rules are same for C and C++. Here is a related part of C11 standard:

#### 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators

> 3. The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The type of the result is
>      that of the promoted left operand. If the value of the right operand is negative or is
> 4. The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with
>      zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2E2, reduced modulo
>      one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed
>      type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is
>      the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> 5. The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type
>      or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>      part of the quotient of E1 / 2E2. If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
>      resulting value is implementation-defined.

Comment: But it seems the behavior is _defined_. It always returns `12`.

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto Undefined behavior can cause compiler to do whatever it wants. If it always does something in a same way, it does not mean that it's well-defined. It's like saying that `*(int*)0 = 0;` is defined because it always crashes.

Comment: gcc loves to ignore any statement that would invoke undefined behaviour. This would give the expected result: `for (int i=0; i< 8; i++) a <<= sizeof(a);
`

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto _Undefined behavior_ means that a compiler is free to do what it wants. It could even summon demons to destroy the world if it knows how. In this instance, the compiler knows it's undefined behavior, so it removes the shift operation entirely.

Comment: Out of curiosity, it just sounds quite rational the result being zero, so why did GCC writers define it _undefined_?

Comment: @HiI'mFrogatto: Random generator: `int rand(void) { return 3; }` guaranteed random, I rolled a dice. Please read what _undefined behaviour_ implies, it is not the same as random! This knowledge is **vital** in programming in general and especially C! That how the standard defines it: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: The question is about C, not C++. They are different languages! Also please reference/state the standard (resp. the final draft), not a second/third source. They are not authoritative. Also right shift does not "usually copy the leftmost bit". There are as many architectures which don't provide an arithmetic right shift.

Comment: @Olaf I've added the reference. The "usually copies the leftmost bit" is taken from cppreference. It says that "most architectures" do it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: Yes, but cppreference mostly is for C++ (that's what they atareted as, at least). They tend to ignore the much larger majority of devices which don't use x86 or even ARMv7A (not to speak of the older ARMs). Fact is there's **decades** more 8/16(/32) bit MCUs than PC-alike CPUs/SoCs. Most PC-People forget about this fact. Just remove this last half-sentence, it is unnecessary at best.